# How to calculate angles of an object relative to gravity based on rotation

Tags: solid-geometry

Considering a cube which is along $x,y,z$ axes, $y$ being parallel with gravity, at its "resting" point, $x$ and $z$ will be running at 90 degrees relative to gravity, and $y$ will be $0$ (parallel).

[image]

If I rotate this cube 30 degrees around the $z$ axis, those angles will now be:
$x: 60, y: 30, z: 90$. Simple calculation...

[image]

My question is, if I then perform another rotation through a different axis, how do I now calculate these angles? My basic trigonometry is ok but I don't even know where to start with 3D geometry.

[image]

Comment: A diagram would be helpful.

Comment: Start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Comment: @K.defaoite added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's vectorize our points:
x = (1, 0, 0);
y = (0, 1, 0);
z = (0, 0, 1);
The force of gravity is (0, 1, 0) = g;
As @Aretino points out, we can use the 3D rotation matrices. So, if we want to rotate a degrees around the x-axis, b degrees around the y-axis, and c degrees around the z-axis, we can do the following:
x * Rx(a) = x' //note here x' is not a derivative but the new value of the vector x.
x' * Ry(b) = x''
x'' * Rz(c) = x'''
Now we can take the dot product of x''' * g = |x'''| * |g| * cos(theta).
Divide the dot product by the product of both vector's lengths.
Then take the arccos of that and you will get the angle in-between the two vectors.
You can repeat this process for the y and z vectors. Hope this helps.

Comment: Please consider using MathJax.

Comment: @Matthew B, I think I understand the basic gist of how you're arriving at the answer, but I don't really understand what $Ry(a)$ is, nor what $x'''$ is with respect to $|x'''|$

Comment: @ChrisA Ry(a) is the 3D rotation matrix for rotating about the y-axis ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations ). x''' is a vector. The dot product of two vectors (x''' and g) is equal to the length of each vector (|x'''|, |g|) times the cosine of the angle between each vector, cos(a) in this case. In this case, x', x'', and x''' are the same vector as x but in a different coordinate system.

Comment: OK, @MatthewB, it looks like I need to do some reading on rotation matrices. Tentatively accepting this answer :)